# Why we do not add salt water to the batteries instead of acid?

Tags: acid-base, electrochemistry, conductivity

Actually I was just thinking that since we add acid to the batteries to increase the conductivity but the thought simply crossed my mind that salt are strong electrolytes so there should be a good conductor to and also they are quite cheap so why we do not add salt water to the batteries is electrolysis a possible reason please explain in simple terms.

Comment: We only add acid to lead/acid batteries. Here is an explanation of how they work  https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/lead_based_batteries

Comment: Which batteries ? Lithium ions ? Lead ? Cadmium-nickel ?

Answer (score 5):

All depends on the used electrochemical system. The electrolyte is the part of this system, it is not just a passive medium to conduct the current.

Some systems work in acidic environments like acid lead cells, some use salts like the Daniell cell, some use alkaline solutions like nickel-cadmium or nickel-metalhydride cells, and some do not even use water in their electrolytes, like Li-Ion batteries ( using mostly LiPF6 in mixture of dialkylcarbonates ).

Answer (score 2):

There is a very valid reason for using acid in batteries, where needed. You are right that salts are also good conductors but keep in mind they are not the *best* conductors. In aqueous solutions, proton is the best conductor known! Which ion is no. 2? Not surprisingly, the hydroxide ion. Look at the comparison, there is no match for proton in  [various tables](https://www.google.com/search?q=molar%20conductivity%20of%20ions&safe=off&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiB3f2Iw5XqAhVOS6wKHfx4C6wQ_AUoAXoECBEQAw&biw=1536&bih=674).

[image]